# Nodejs store billions of images in a file system

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filesystems, multer, directory-structure

I'm new to nodejs and currently I'm working on a Node Web API with mongodb database.

- According to project requirements users should be able to upload
  their profile pictures and cover photos.
- And There can be billions of user accounts

After doing some research, I have found that "storing images in a file system is better than storing in database"

So now my plan is to save images in a file system. 
But,
 - There is a limited number of files can be placed in a one folder (based on OS)
 - should be able to access files quickly

because of above requirements, In order to store large number of images, We need to have a good folder structure and a naming policy.

Can anyone suggest any good naming algorithm and a folder structure to store billions of profile pics ?

(currently I'm accessing users by object Id's generated by mongodb)

Comment: have you considered services like google storage?

Comment: Yes i'm planing to use a cloud service, But the issue is with, how to store files properly. Because I'll need do save the image reference in database.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a folder for each user (if the OS supports so many folders in one place) and store the user information that isn't stored in the database in there.

The database entry for user should contain an additional entry which is called "data_folder_id" which contains the number of the folder on the filesystem. Or you can name the folders according to the user ID directly.

An example folder structure:

```
[user_data] // The folder which will contain the data from your all your users
    [1] // The data folder from user 1
        [profile_photo.png] // Profile photo from user 1
        [cover_photo.png] // Cover photo from user 1

    [2]
        [profile_photo.png]
        [cover_photo.png]

    [3]
        [profile_photo.png]
        [cover_photo.png]

    [...]
```

If you can't store so many folders in one place you have to split them up in subfolders like:

```
[user_data] // The folder which will contain the data from all your users
    [1-50] // Contains user folders 1 to 50
        [1] // The data folder from user 1
            [profile_photo.png] // Profile photo from user 1
            [cover_photo.png] // Cover photo from user 1

        [2]
            [profile_photo.png]
            [cover_photo.png]

        [...]

    [51-100]
        [51]
            [profile_photo.png]
            [cover_photo.png]

        [52]
            [profile_photo.png]
            [cover_photo.png]

    [...]
```

Comment: But what is the logic to distribute images among folders

Comment: @AchiraShamal I added a statement which should clarify where the user numbers come from. Does this answer your question?

Comment: One more issue, I'm referencing users by the object Id (mongodb) , And I don't think creating a folder per user is not a good practice.

Comment: @AchiraShamal I am not sure if I understood you correctly. You can name the folders like you want. Of course you can use the object ID from mongodb instead of a user ID if you want to.